# Ruby - how to correctly pass an object as parameter and then display it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am passing an object like this:

```
-@users.each do |user|
          %tr
            %td=link_to(user.first_name, users_user_path(user), :title => user.first_name)
            %td=user.first_name
```

but I am not exactly sure how to retrieve the user object in the controller. I try something like this:

```
user = User.new(params[:@user])
@user = params[:@user]
```

But nothing like that works.  How is this supposed to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.. to get the user in the controller, you would do:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user])
```

Comment: that works, but then the object has all nil fields after I do an inspect.  Do you know why that might happen? Thank you

Comment: Can you add more info to your question on exactly what you are trying to do, and show some more code?

Comment: Do you post the user info in a form?  From what you have posted in your question, it look like you do a link which indicate you try to do a GET to show a user already present in the database!

Comment: Yes I am doing a get but I am passing the object so I don't think I should need to go to the database..right?

Comment: @flynfish the user field is an object. My understanding of the code is that I am passing the object and then somehow when I retrieve it in the controller, all the fields are nil.

Comment: @Genadinik Can you update your question to include your controller code? And also include your view code including the form.